# Hanlding multiple browser windows using Testcomplete

Tags: testcomplete

Can any one help in below scenario using testcomplete.

I need to handle two browser windows and verify some text on two browser windows.
Please let me know how to take two browser windows and pages instances to an array using JScript.

Thanks,
Naveen.

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs of the pages are different, you can assign the page objects to separate variables and work with them further.

```
var page1 = Sys.Browser("chrome").Page("http://www.google.com");
var page2 = Sys.Browser("chrome").Page("http://www.smartbear.com");
```

Comment: Both the page URL's are same. Please let me know any other way of doing it by taking indexing of the browser or page title of the browser. How to take these two browser page instances to different variables..

Comment: In this case, you can differentiate these pages by their content. So, you can find a page instance containing an object that does not exist on the second instance of the page. You can create a function that will perform this intellectual search for a page and use it when you need to get a specific page from your test.